# Explain why there is a minimizer for the function $E:p \mapsto\left \| p-f \right \|_{\infty}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $Q_n$ be the space of polynomials of maximal degree $n$ such that each $p\in Q_n$ satisfies $p(0) = p(1) = 0$. Let $f\in C([a,b])$ so that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Explain why among all $p\in Q_n$, there is a minimizer for the function $E:p \mapsto\left \| p-f \right \|_{\infty}$.

My idea is the following:

I know that because $f$ is a continuous, real-valued function on an interval, there has to be a polynomial $p$ in $Q_n$ so that $||p-f||_\infty$ and either $p=f$ or $f-p$ satisfies equioscillation condition of degree $n$. But what to do from here?

Comment: I would argue from the fact that $Q_n$ is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $Q_n$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $C[a,b]$, and so it is closed. More importantly, its closed balls are compact.

So choose $k>0$ big enough so that there exists $p\in Q_n$ with $\|f-p\|<k$. Note that the function $E$ is continuous: by the triangle inequality, 
$$
|E(p)-E(q)|=|\|p-f\|-\|f-q\||\leq\|p-q\|. 
$$
The closed ball $\overline{B_k(0)}$ of radius $k$ in $Q_n$ is compact, and so its image through $E$ is also compact. Then $E$ achieves its minimum on $\overline{B_k(0)}$.